# Missing $ inserted, again

Tags: siunitx

I've tried a number of things to get this thing to work, to no avail.

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{lineno}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{mhchem}
    \usepackage{textgreek}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}

\begin{document}

\ce{K_M} (0.04 \si\micro\ M), 

\ce{V_{max}} (0.738\si\micro\ /min, and 

\ce{K_{cat}}(23.6 min^-1). 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide a Minimal Working Example. In your case, it is very likely that you will solve your problem by yourself while reducing your code to the minimal code reproducing the error.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of simplifying your example code further, to have it focus on the essentials. Hope you don't mind. Incidentally, which units to `M` and `min` denote: "mole" and "minute", or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: As `(23.6 min^-1)` is not in math mode `^` causes the error…

Answer (score 7):

I'd use the `\SI` macro of the `siunitx` package to typeset both the numbers and the units. If you mean to refer to units such as "mole" and "per minute", don't write out the symbols; instead, use `\mole` and `\per\minute` inside the second argument of `\SI`.

Incidentally, I can't get the "micro" symbol to show up if `\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}` is in effect; are you maybe using a non-default font?

*Update*: Modified the code per @clemens's informed guess and @mchem's request (see comment below).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}
\DeclareSIUnit{\molar}{M} % per @clemens's note

\begin{document} 
$K_M$ (\SI{0.04}{\micro\molar})

$V_{\max}$ (\SI{0.738}{\micro\molar\per\minute})

$K_{\textrm{cat}}$ (\SI{23.6}{\per\minute}) 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was actually given a template by a friend.. Don't know from where. Is there a way to change the font back to normal? Apologies, but this is my first day using LaTeX. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @colonelk1 - Can you live without the `\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}` directive?

Comment: Sure. I only tried using it as an alternative, doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: What's confusing is that     \textmu appears to work fine except in that situation where I linked it. I'm really not sure why.

Comment: The uppercase `M` in the first example suggests the OP wants `\DeclareSIUnit{\molar}{M}` and `\ce{K_M} (\SI{0.04}{\micro\molar})`

Comment: As an aside I'm failing to see what unit `\micro{}\per\minute` should be. My guess is `\micro\molar\per\minute`. Also neither `\ce{K_M}`, `\ce{V_{max}}` nor `\ce{K_{cat}}` do make sense: they're not chemical compounds but mathematical variables (most likely velocity constants (k) and velocity (v))

Comment: @clemens - I fully share your misgivings. The main aim of my answer was to show how the OP's non-compilable code might be made to compile; that's how I came up with, e.g., the change from `23.6 min^-1` to `\SI{23.6}{\per\minute}`. What the meaning of such an expression may be (and even if it has usable meaning...) is not for me to assess...

Comment: Hi Clemens, thanks for catching that error. I do indeed want microM per minute.Km, Vmax and Kcat are variables that relate to enzyme kinetics (biochemistry).

Comment: Mico, thank you very much for the help. It was definitely time-consuming but I went and used your fix for the things that gave me an error. It finally works!

Comment: @colonelk1 - You're most welcome!

Comment: @colonelk1 in that case you probably want `$K_M$` instead of `\ce{K_M}`. *Every* style I know typesets variables in italic (also math mode does make more sense semantically). If you really need them upright there are better ways than using `mhchem`'s `\ce`.

Comment: @Mico Could you please modify your solution and remove the misuse of mhchem's `\ce`?

Comment: @mhchem - Please see the new code and screenshot.